# Is there a way to put gradient color to address bar in android device?

Tags: html, css, web, layout, meta-tags

Well this is a method of giving colour for address bar

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="hexadecimal value">
```

This will give color to your address bar in chrome and other browser.

Is there a way to put gradient colors?

These are the colors I want :#cc2b5e,#753a88

Comment: I guess currently there is no [support](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android#disqus_thread) for this

Comment: Okay! So there is non way to add gradient colors. So I have to go by simple colors. Well thanks for informing me.

Comment: To add multiple colors in this meta tag, please refer to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63798201/10738806)