# Animation of meta name="theme-color"

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, meta-tags

I want to use an animation consisting of several colors, in `<meta name="theme-color" content="...">` *eg: #87CEFA , #1E90FF , #4169E1...*

Is it possible to animate the `theme-color` in Chrome on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to this problem with the following JavaScript code. With this code, 3 theme-colors on browser's URL bar change dynamically.

```js
var themeColorTest = new function() {
  function e() {
    "#87CEFA" === $themeColor.content ? $themeColor.content = "#1E90FF" : "#1E90FF" === $themeColor.content ? $themeColor.content = "#4169E1" : $themeColor.content = "#87CEFA",
      setTimeout(e, 500)
  }
  this.init = function() {
    $themeColor = document.querySelector("meta[name='theme-color']"),
      e()
  }
};
themeColorTest.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Animation of meta name theme-color</title>
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#87CEFA" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>More info on the <code>theme-color</code> meta tag is at this <a href="https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android?hl=en">Google Developers Blog Post</a>.</p>
</body>

</html>
```